# how to combine php array of object by unique id?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have these 2 arrays.

First array is from user input `$cart`:

```
$cart = [
   ['id' => 3, 'weight' => 20, 'percentage' => 80],
   ['id' => 1, 'weight' => 50, 'percentage' => 80],
   ['id' => 2, 'weight' => 40, 'percentage' => 80],
];
```

and second array, I do a database `SELECT id, stock WHERE id IN (3,1,2)`, resulting `$db_item`

```
$db_item = [
    ['id' => 1, 'stock' => 9539.00],
    ['id' => 2, 'stock' => 9468.00],
    ['id' => 3, 'stock' => 9295.00],
];
```

I want to add the stock attribute in second array to first array.
Expected output:

```
$cart = [
   ['id' => 3, 'weight' => 20, 'percentage' => 80, 'stock' => 9295.00],
   ['id' => 1, 'weight' => 50, 'percentage' => 80, 'stock' => 9539.00],
   ['id' => 2, 'weight' => 40, 'percentage' => 80, 'stock' => 9468.00],
];
```

This is what I tried, and it works, but I don't think it is necessary to have `foreach`, `array_filter`, and `array_column`:

```
foreach ($cart as $key => $cart_item) {
    $item = array_filter($db_item, function($item) use ($cart_item) {
        return $item['id'] === $cart_item['id'];
    });
    $cart[$key]['stock'] = array_column($item, 'stock')[0];
}
```

anyone has better idea how to optimize this?

---

**EDIT:** following [Mohammad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53339141/3671954), I can use more attribute in second array

```
$keys = [];
foreach ($arr2 as $item) {
    $keys[$item['id']] = array(
        'attr1' => $item['attr1'],
        'attr2' => $item['attr2'],
        // and so on
    );
}

$newArr = array_map(function($item) use($keys){
    $item['attr1'] = $keys[$item['id']]['attr1'];
    $item['attr2'] = $keys[$item['id']]['attr2'];
    // and so on
    return $item;
}, $arr1);
```

**EDIT2:** found out that we can simplify the foreach loop with just a single line using `array_column`.

```
$keys = array_column($arr2, null, 'id');

$newArr = array_map(function($item) use($keys){
    $item['attr1'] = $keys[$item['id']]['attr1'];
    $item['attr2'] = $keys[$item['id']]['attr2'];
    // and so on
    return $item;
}, $arr1);
```

Comment: Why not get all the required data in a single query. If you show us the 2 queries, someone will tell you how to get all the info in one query

Comment: @RiggsFolly but first array is from user input, not from the query

Comment: Ah, good point :) Missed that :) :(

Comment: Funny thing, I have something of this nature in a cart system, but I just used two foreach... which is most likely the same performance as array_filter, since it rolls over the array just the same. We are talking mini-milli-seconds, so you probably are ok with what you have... unless you just want to make it more readable for anyone coming along your code in the future.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Yeah considering the cart probably not gonna exceed 20 items, the difference in tiime should not that obvious. So, it's not urgent, I can continue with my work, but maybe in the future I have to do this with thousands of items at once, I will need optimization.

Comment: In programming, one of the best ways to optimize array lookups is the use of hash tables.  PHP's associative arrays are an easy to use form of this.   However, when dealing with only a  few elements,  I think any optimization is overoptimization.

Comment: @Devon hahaha, now I begin to think that I shouldn't overthinking things too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use combination of `array_flip()` and `array_column()` to create array contain `id` and index of second array.

Then use `array_map()` to add new key `stock` to first array.

```
$keys = array_flip(array_column($arr2, 'id'));
$newArr = array_map(function($item) use($keys, $arr2){ 
    $item['stock'] = $arr2[$keys[$item['id']]]['stock'];
    return $item;
}, $arr1);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/EfdTM)

Also you can use `foreach` instead of `array_flip()`

```
$keys = [];
foreach ($arr2 as $item)
    $keys[$item['id']] = $item['stock'];

$newArr = array_map(function($item) use($keys){ 
    $item['stock'] = $keys[$item['id']];
    return $item;
}, $arr1);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/7PFAA)

Comment: this is the first time I see the use of array_flip. Nice idea btw, it is 2 lines shorter.
But isn't doing array_flip + array_column + array_map is also doing 3 loops just like my solution above?
I like your second solution, gonna change my code to use yours.

Answer (score 1):

This can help too, one array_column + one array_map :

```
$arr2=array_column($arr2,'stock','id');
$arr1=array_map(function($val)use($arr2){$val['stock']=$arr2[$val['id']];return $val;},$arr1);
```

Comment: Oh nice, didn't know about array_column third parameter before.